# multiplying every element of a vector by every other element to form a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, vector

How do you create a matrix from a vector, with the matrix containing the products of every possible pair of elements in the vector.

Simple example:

```
vec <- c(1:3)

result <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6, 3, 6, 9), ncol=3)
```

I'm thinking there is one simple function for doing this, but I can't find it!

Comment: it's just `outer(vec, vec)`

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was going to be one of those one-function answers..

Comment: You can also try `vec %o% vec` (which is the same)

Comment: @DavidArenburg why'd you delete your answer?

Comment: @MatthewPlourde, cause you already answered in comments.